# Selecting specific items from lists

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am trying to make "Who's that Pokemon" in Python.
I have uploaded different image files to my folder. Some are silhouette versions of the pokemon, while others show the actual Pokemon. I put the names of these image files into two seperate lists. One list is for silhouette images; the other is for non-silhouette images.

I am trying to figure out how I can select an name from one of the lists while at the same time making sure it matches up with the final product. For example, if I pick a Pikachu sliouette, how do I make it so that when I click on the awnser, it shows the image of Pikachu instead of a different Pokemon?

Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import random


#pop up window creation
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Who's that Pokemon? AP CSP Project by Ethan Wong")
window.wm_geometry("850x500")


#list of silo image name files
silo_list = ['pikachusilo.png', 'rowletsilo.png', 'dugtriosilo.png']
#noraml list (non-silo images)
non_silo_list = ['pikachu.png', 'rowlet.png', 'dugtrio.png']

silo_pick = random.choice(silo_list)
normal_pick = random.choice(non_silo_list)


#silo images (opens up the silo images)
silo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(silo_pick)) #google.com (image source)
silo = tk.Label(image=silo_image)
silo.pack()

#normal (non-silo images)
normal_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(normal_pick))
normal = tk.Label(image=normal_image)


#how the button works (displays the normal image)
def clickfoward():
    normal.pack()

#button atempt
fowardbutton = tk.Button(window, text="see the answer!", command=clickfoward)
fowardbutton.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

But, I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Don't make it two separate lists.  Make it one list with tuples of two strings.  That way, when you make a selection, you get both names.

Comment: Alternatively, create a class to store both images. This not only allows you to associate the "normal" image with the silouette, but you can also add any other fields to the class that you want, such as the name.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
images = [
    ('pikachu.png','pikachusilo.png'),
    ('rowlet.png','rowletsilo.png'),
    ('dugtrio.png','dugtriosilo.png')
]
```

Alternatively, if you STRICTLY follow that naming rule, where the silhouette name is the full image with "silo" added before the dot, you can easily generate one from the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` to bind the image of the Pokemon with its corresponding silouette image.

Change this:

```py
silo_pick = random.choice(silo_list)
normal_pick = random.choice(non_silo_list)
```

to

```py
silo_pick, normal_pick = random.choice(zip(silo_list, non_silo_list))
```

`zip()` programmatically generates the list of 2-tuples (as seen in [Tim Roberts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576492/17769815)), and then the LHS assigns the first element of that tuple to `silo_pick`, the second to `normal_pick`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, naturally, this only works if the order in which the file names appear in both lists is the same.